# Bootstrap 3: Push/pull issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to setup a template where I have two sidebars, right and left, and content in the middle. No problem so far for desktop:

**Desktop view**

[image: Desktop view]

But I want it to realign for mobile so that the content is on top, the sidebars underneath, the left one one the left side and the right one on the right side.

**Desired mobile view**

[image: Desired mobile view]

Can I achieve it without having to use JS for moving the `div`s?

Here's a Bootply that shows my issue: http://www.bootply.com/133440

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your elements should always be the one you want in the most narrow view (mobile). Then pull and push elements in larger views with `col-md-pull-4`, `col-md-push-8`, etc to get the view you want.

Here's what you wanted I believe : http://jsfiddle.net/aws9pv88/7/